# Invoke-GPUpdate fails even with firewall disabled

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-v3.0

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer rim-23
Invoke-GPUpdate :  Computer "rim-23" is not responding. The target computer is either turned off or Remote
Scheduled Tasks Management Firewall rules are disabled.
Parameter name: computer
```

I have all the remote services running and firewall for the domain profile disabled. However, I still have no luck with getting an invoke-gpudate command to run.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Have you verified name resolution and basic connectivity for the remote computer?

Comment: Yep. The name works fine as everything else that uses the computer name had no problem.

Comment: See if you can connect to the target computer "rim-23" with the Scheduled Tasks MMC, as it looks like that's what Invoke-GPUpdate wants to do.

Comment: is winrm enabled on the remote host?  When you say the firewall is disabled, you mean it's off or that the service is now set to disabled?  Can you ping or connect to remote management ports?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to ensure the "Remote Scheduled Tasks Management" local firewall rules are enabled on the machine